# How to implement the JMS Asynchronous Message Receiver

Tags: java, jms

To receive Jboss JMS messsage, I have written the JMS Asynchronous Message Receiver

See below code

```
public class QueueReceive implements MessageListener
{

 public final static String JNDI_FACTORY="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory";


 public final static String JMS_FACTORY="ConnectionFactory";

 public final static String QUEUE="/queue/requestQueue";

 private QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;
 private QueueConnection qcon;
 private QueueSession qsession;
 private QueueReceiver qreceiver;
 private Queue queue;
 private boolean quit = false;

 public void onMessage(Message msg)
 {
    try {
        System.out.println("onMessage");
     String msgText;
     if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
       msgText = ((TextMessage)msg).getText();
     } else {
       msgText = msg.toString();
     }

     System.out.println("Message Received: "+ msgText );

     if (msgText.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
       synchronized(this) {
         quit = true;
         this.notifyAll(); // Notify main thread to quit
       }
     }
    } catch (JMSException jmse) {
     System.err.println("An exception occurred: "+jmse.getMessage());
    }
 }


 public void init(Context ctx, String queueName)
    throws NamingException, JMSException
 {
    qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
    qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
    qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(queueName);
    qreceiver = qsession.createReceiver(queue);
    qreceiver.setMessageListener(this);
    qcon.start();



 }

 public void close()throws JMSException
 {
    qreceiver.close();
    qsession.close();
    qcon.close();
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    InitialContext ic = getInitialContext("jnp://host:port");
    QueueReceive qr = new QueueReceive();
    System.out.println("Ready to initialize");
    qr.init(ic, QUEUE);

    System.out.println("JMS Ready To Receive Messages (To quit, send a \"quit\" message).");
   // qr.onMessage(qr.qreceiver.receive());
    System.out.println("Message Receivd");
    // Wait until a "quit" message has been received.
    synchronized(qr) {
     while (!qr.quit) {
       try {
         qr.wait();
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
     }
    }
    qr.close();
 }

 private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url)
    throws NamingException
 {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    return new InitialContext(env);
 }
}
```

When I run java program, it will not call the onMessage method directly, Please help me how to received the JMS message.

From this code I am able to ping the JMS messenger and unable to read the message?

Comment: Who is putting messages on the queue?

Comment: @mikea sorry now messages are coming from the queue. plz help me how to stop the jms messages listener

Comment: So what is your actual question? Stopping to receive message? Getting message? Stopping the producer?